# Do we use the word "feature" to talk about people?

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

It obviously sounds odd to say "he has a lot of great features." But can we use the word "traits" instead?And what if we say "he has a lot of great behavioral features"? Would that sound natural? Thanks a lot

Comment: What exactly are you trying to describe? (It does ***not*** obviously sound odd, to me, to say *he has a lot of great features* if you're talking about his nose and chin, for instance. But even if you're talking about his personality, *features* can be used in the right context. So, what's the complete sentence and its surrounding sentences? (*Behavioural features* sounds just fine in the context of a scientific journal, but not so much in everyday dialogue.)

Comment: I mean their personality, but you mean whether we're talking about one's looks or their personality we can use the word "features"? Like "I love her face, she has lots of great features (meaning nose, lips, etc)."? And the same is true about their behavioral characteristics?

Answer (score 2):

> It obviously sounds odd to say "he has a lot of great features."

I disagree about "feature" being odd, especially when it is used in reference to physical characteristics like eye color or shape of nose.

> But can we use the word "traits" instead?

Absolutely.  "He has a lot of great traits" is perfectly natural sounding.

> And what if we say "he has a lot of great behavioral features"? Would that sound natural?

This is fine, if possibly a tad on the clinical-sounding side

Comment: Your answer has a many great features. :-) You might want to add a definition, e.g., https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/feature.